# Ubuntu 18 server throwing Apache Error with Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, apache

I'm getting these 2 errors in appache error log. anyone have experience with this?

Running:
Ubuntu Linux 18.04.1, Apache version 2.4.29, PHP 7.2

This is on a Wordpress. (could be the error is caused by a php plugin missing?)
The page shows a didn’t send any data.  ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE in chrome

```
double free or corruption (out)
[Mon Oct 22 18:49:54.087007 2018] [core:notice] [pid 1612] AH00051: child pid 13086 exit signal Aborted (6), possible coredump in /etc/apache2
```

Comment: Do you get this same error if you try to load a static (non-PHP) page? That might help you rule out a PHP issue.

Comment: no, its just on 1 page, i think caused by php error. but php does not show error.